# Uniqueness of Limit in an Ordered Field

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, ordered-fields

Let $K$ be an ordered field. Then $K$ contains a unique copy of the ordered field $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, we can define the absolute value $|\cdot|$ and sequence convergence in exactly the same way as in $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, a sequence $(a_n)\subset K$ is said to converge to $l\in K$ if
$$
\forall\epsilon\in K(\epsilon>0\to\exists N\in\mathbb{N}(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}(n\geq N\to|a_n-l|<\epsilon)))
$$

> **Question:** In general, will $l$ be unique? If not, what is wrong with the usual proof given below?
>
> I'm asking since it was remarked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060455/are-the-hyperreals-complete) that it will *not* in general. The example of the hyperreals in which every other point infinitesimally close to $l$ will also be a limit of $(a_n)$ was given.

**Proof (possibly flawed)**: Suppose $l,l'$ are two limits of $(a_n)$. WLOG, suppose that $l'<l$. Let $\epsilon:=\frac{l'-l}{2}>0$, so that there exists $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq n_1$ then
$$
|a_n-l|<\frac{l'-l}{2}
$$
Also, there exists $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq N_2$ then
$$
|a_n-l'|<\frac{l'-l}{2}
$$
If $N:=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, then
$$
a_N-l<\frac{l'-l}{2}\text{ and }-\frac{l'-l}{2}<a_N-l'
$$
so
$$
\frac{l'+l}{2}<a_N<\frac{l'+l}{2}
$$
which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof of uniqueness works fine.  The problem (if one thinks of it as a problem) is that for example the sequence $(1/n)$ need not have a limit.

Comment: Then should I conclude that the affirmation "In [the ordered field of the hyperreals] the limit of a Cauchy sequence is not unique. It converges to every point which is infinitesimally close to any other limit point." is false?

Comment: I have only checked the correctness of your proof, given your definition of limit. If we change the definition, by saying that for every positive integer $k$, there is an $N$ such that if $n\gt N$ then $|a_n-l|\lt 1/k$, then it is true that limit need not be unique. But you asked instead that for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, $\dots$. That is a much stronger condition. As to Cauchy sequences, if a Cauchy sequence has a limit (using your definition of limit), yes, it will be unique.

Comment: @Guest In hyperreals the sequence $1/n$ is not Cauchy - for any infinitesimal $\varepsilon$, we always have $|1/n-1/m|>\varepsilon$.